# Kubuntu 16.04 - PHP 5.6 - mssql driver

Tags: php, linux, pdo

I just updated my kubuntu box, and PHP got updated to 7.x.

Now, as of PHP 7.x does not have the `mssql_*` deprecated functions, I need to downgrade to php 5.6. (PDO dblib is way to slow for this project)

Though [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) does not have the mssql extension for php 5.6.

Is there any way I can force kubuntu to downgrade PHP ?

Comment: Probably this should be moved to Server Fault?

Comment: You can always remove PHP and then re-install an old version.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I removed the ondrej sources and updated, apt-cache madison php, reports php | 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 - How do I force this to 5.6 ?

Comment: I believe this guide and these sources may be relevant for your case: https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix nope, also using ondrej/php ppa - which does not give you mssql

Comment: I see the problem, perhaps then this could help? https://gist.github.com/joecampo/acd1e5881aee08bd8959

Comment: This uses PDO, I need to use mssql_query

Answer (score 0):

che your repository list if you have this repo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/"

if yes, remove all php packages and install your stack with:

```
apt-get install php5.6-mysql php5.6-sqlite
```

if no, remove all old ondrej repository and add the new repo:

```
 ppa:ondrej/php
 deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu <version> main
```

Comment: `ppa:ondrej/php` does not have mssql driver.

Comment: you need to run only:
apt-get install php5-sybase php5.5-odbc

Comment: php5-sybase does not exists in ondrej/php

Comment: yeps i know, it's in the kubuntu database, but works